# how can i solve [ControllerAction] attribute that can not solve by mvc engine?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi i made some googling to achive this stuff .

https://code.google.com/p/mvccontrib/source/browse/branches/TagHelpers/src/MvcContrib.Samples.NHamlViewEngine/Controllers/ProductsController.cs?r=144

also

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/09/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios.aspx

i downloaded https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVC3ControlsToolkit/   but i can not solve below problem. Vs2012 can not detect   [ControllerAction] attribute. Do you have any info?:

[image]

Comment: I don't think you need to use [ControllerAction] anymore: [http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/08/extending-asp.net-mvc-to-add-conventions.aspx/](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/08/extending-asp.net-mvc-to-add-conventions.aspx/)

Comment: Yuo are write. But why do i need ContollerAction. is it old stuff?

Comment: It is old stuff, you don't need it because MVC now uses `ProductController : Controller`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ControllerAction attribute was used in a pre-release version of MVC (going back about 6 years I think). Its no longer required (and probably no longer exists).

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`public void Category(int id)` with `public ActionResult Category(int id)` and

`RenderView("List", category)` with `return View("List", category)`

and remove `[ControllerAction]` attribute